# Can't fix NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception

I've been trying to add to the Y coordinate after randomizing the X coordinate of some lines. It's giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at uy.com.vincent.map.Background.tick(Background.java:24)
at uy.com.vincent.Game.tick(Game.java:40)
at uy.com.vincent.Game.run(Game.java:90)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
private int lineX[] = new int[50];
private int lineY[] = new int[50];
private Game game;

public Background(Game game) {
    for(int i = 0; i < lineX.length; i++) {
        lineX[i] = getRandom(game.getCanvas().getWidth());
        lineY[i] = 0;
    }
}

public void tick() {
    for(int i = 0; i < lineX.length; i++) {
        if(lineY[i] >= game.getCanvas().getHeight() + 100) { // Line 24
            lineX[i] = getRandom(game.getCanvas().getWidth()); 
            lineY[i] = 0;
        }
        lineY[i] += 1;
    }
}

public int getRandom(int max) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int generatedRandom = random.nextInt(max + 1);
    return generatedRandom;
}
```

I'm sorry if the solution is obvious. I'm still learning.

Comment: Do you write `game = ...` anywhere?

Comment: You never set your game in the constructor.

Comment: Worked... I feel stupid now. Thanks :)